# Get a list of GitHub runners?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, github-actions

I am fairly new to GitHub workflow/actions and tasked with getting a list of our current runners matching runners.  I am across this statement looking at an existing workflow.

```
runs-on: ["self-hosted", "management-control-plane", "${{ needs.env.outputs.env }}"]
```

So it looks like its saying 'find one our existing VM with specified tag 'management-control-plane' in the specified environment.  So, Github as a list of these somewhere that its referencing.

**Question:** How can I query the list of VMs using a tag and environment?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the REST API to list all runners for your organisation or repository.

Here's a sample from the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/rest/reference/actions#self-hosted-runners):

```
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG/actions/runners
```

```
{
  "total_count": 2,
  "runners": [
    {
      "id": 23,
      "name": "linux_runner",
      "os": "linux",
      "status": "online",
      "busy": true,
      "labels": [
        {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "self-hosted",
          "type": "read-only"
        },
        {
          "id": 7,
  // etc...
```

Comment: do I replace 'orgs' or 'ORG' my company's repo or something like that?

Comment: runners can be defined on org level or repo level. Assuming you have installed them on the org level, you replace ORG.